# can't see adapter gui

Tags: android, user-interface, android-arrayadapter

I can't see my listAdapter. I pass to it a list of my items and my list isn't empty but I get just an empty screen.
If you can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Here my code, my main activity is this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //  setContentView(R.layout.listitems);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        RssArrays RssArrays=(RssArrays) extras.get("rssItem");
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // on test
        listAdpterRss   listAdapter = new listAdpterRss(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listitems,RssArrays);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter); // on test

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                //new splash(ListRss.this,mHandler,listValue.get(position).toString()).execute();
            } 

        });


    }}
```

and my adpter is

```
public listAdpterRss(Context context, int textViewResourceId ,RssArrays list ) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);           
        mContext = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = list ;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
    {    
        View mView = v;

    if(mView == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
    }




    TextView tx = (TextView) mView .findViewById(R.id.textView);

    //if this view is on main screen
    if (tx==null){

        tx=((TextView) mView);
    }
    tx.setText(items.PodcastTitle[position]);
```

Comment: did you override all the methods like getCount() .... (if you are using a base adapter) ?

Comment: You need to edit your question and add proper formatting and that might seem compilable. Right now your question is not useful for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass the dataset to the super or `override getCount()` and let it returns the numeber of item inside `RssArray`. Only in this way the `getView()` will be called.

use this [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29)